# Run something as soon as the notebook is open

Tags: dynamic, notebooks, system, scheduling, hyerplink

I want to create a .nb file, say `DoSomethingAsSoonAsOpen.nb`, such that

***in any case*** as soon as `DoSomethingAsSoonAsOpen.nb` file is open,

(***in any case*** means
by mouse double clicking `DoSomethingAsSoonAsOpen.nb` on file explorer or
by opening `DoSomethingAsSoonAsOpen.nb` on mathematica menu or
by clicking a hyperlink on another .nb, etc.)

it execute some code, for example it prints `Hello` on `DoSomethingAsSoonAsOpen.nb`.

The first thing I wonder is.. could that code be
**inside** of `DoSomethingAsSoonAsOpen.nb` ? or
it can't be inside of `DoSomethingAsSoonAsOpen.nb`, instead we should create **schedued task** that is running globally?

If both ways are possible, I prefer the case - the code is inside of `DoSomethingAsSoonAsOpen.nb`.

To elaborate, I simplified my question, what I need is not printing 'Hello' on that `DoSomethingAsSoonAsOpen.nb`, the task is a bit complicated, and it includes the process of opening another `.nb`.

Comment: Look into working with initialization cells: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/WorkWithInitializationCells.html

Comment: Thank you, it was helpful! But there is a problem turning off the evaluation warning : https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/297095/initialization-cell-evaluation-warning-turned-off-but-still

Comment: Take a look at `NotebookDynamicExpression`