# Initialization Cell evaluation warning : turned off but still

Tags: evaluation, dynamic, notebooks, system

I have a two .nb files, `MyStart.nb` and `MyDoing.nb` in `c:\testfolder`.

My intention is that if I open `MyStart.nb`, then `MyDoing.nb` will also be opened.
(But it is not my final goal and this is a just testing step)

So the content of `MyStart.nb` is a single line code

```
NotebookOpen["C:testfolder\\MyDoing.nb"];
```

And by using option inspector, I have set
`InitializationCellEvaluation` to `True` and
`InitializationCellWarning` to `False`.

But still mathematica shows a warning :
[image]

Following is a video. Opening `MyStart.nb` leads to opening `MyDoing.nb`, that is good,
but there is till warning, though I disabled warning in `Option Inspector` :

I failed to make the video in to GIF lower then 2MB, I upload the video directly :

https://streamable.com/ufgq3t

Comment: I found the solution by myself. The solution is on the document for `InitializationCellWarning`. We must `also` turn off it in `Global Level` also, because of the security. Double turn off!